# How to create custom abstract objects with attributes in Typo3?

Tags: object, interface, typo3

I am now familiar with "basic" Typo3 - Usage and templating. Right now, I am stuck though, because I am not familiar with custom extensions etc.
I am looking for a way to represent Objects, that I get via methods of my own php-class from an XML-DB-Interface, in Typo3.

To be more precise :

I have a really complex XML-Interface and a php-class which is complete already, to interact with that interface, making methods available, that are meant to interact with different object-types in the underlying DB.

I now want to create abstract objects with the corresponding attributes in Typo3 to be able to work with them in typo3 (display/create/modify).
Furthermore, it would be helpful to find a way to "link" the functions of my php class to typo3-functions, so I can (perhaps?!) build up some kind of simple report-generator that generates conditional reports of those objects.

Could anybody lead me into the right direction and link (a) HowTo(s) or perhaps even examples that I could modify?

Thanks in advance, Oliver

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check how DBAL extension is coded.
https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/extensions/dbal/

You might want to implement this XML system as your own abstraction system to store your objects and use TYPO3 backend forms to manipulate those.